# spree 0.11.2, rails 2.3.12, missing the spree 0.11.2 gem even though it is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm having trouble with spree 0.11.2 on rails 2.3.12.  I need to get Spree running on Rails 2.3.12.  I have no control over which version of rails installed, but I do over Spree.  I have edited spree's boot.rb to allow rails 2.3.12 and the install goes fine but when ever I run "rake db:bootstrap" or "script/server" I get the below error.  What else do I need to edit?  Or can someone recommend a version of spree that runs with rails 2.3.12 out of the box?

Missing the Spree 0.11.2 gem. Please `gem install -v=0.11.2 spree`, update your SPREE_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out SPREE_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.

*gem list --local spree*

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

spree (0.11.2)

*config/environment.rb*

SPREE_GEM_VERSION = '0.11.2' unless defined? SPREE_GEM_VERSION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your question was on the Spree Groups forum. For edification I thought I would link out to it.

This thread basically articulates that if you're trying to work against Rails 2.3.12, you're going to have to modify hard-coded references to it in the spree source. Spree gem 0.11 is stable against Rails 3.1.8.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spree-user/0KIrgrL7Q-4

You should update to Spree 1.0.0 if you can, and Rails to 3.1.1 for the latest in features, bug fixes, and more.

Check out the legacy documentation if you're still stuck on this:
http://guides.spreecommerce.com/legacy/0-11-x/getting_started.html